# Serialize many-to-many relation with intermediate model in Django Rest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I tried to check another topics, but didn't found a solution...

I have a many-to-many model, that have intermediate model with another field `additional_field` inside.

```
class BoardField(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='')

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='')
    fields = models.ManyToManyField(BoardField, through='ArticleField', through_fields=('article', 'board_field'))

class ArticleField(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='task')
    board_field = models.ForeignKey(BoardField, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    additional_field = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
```

I want serialize `Article` with structure:

```
[
    "title":"Title",
    "fields":[
        {
            "board_field": {
                "title":"Title"
            },
            "additional_field":"Additional info"
        }
    ]
]
```

So, I wrote serializer:

```
class BoardFieldSrl(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = BoardField
        fields = (
            'title',
        )

class ArticleFieldSrl(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    board_field = BoardFieldSrl()

    class Meta:
        model = ArticleField
        fields = (
            'board_field',
            'additional_field',
        )

class ArticleListSrl(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    fields = ArticleFieldSrl(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = (
            'title',
            'fields',
        )
```

But I always got an error:

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `board_field` on serializer `ArticleFieldSrl`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `BoardField` instance.
Original exception text was: 'BoardField' object has no attribute 'board_field'.
```

I made another several examples, but they doesn't gave my result, that I need... My maximum - I got `BoardField` with levels, but without intermediate model...

Can you help me with serializer, that return structure, that I mentioned above? It must include intermediate model `ArticleField` and nested `BoardField`.

Comment: All of them must be ModelSerializers

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Just mistake. There are ModelSerializer in original code of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `fields = ArticleFieldSrl(source='articlefield_set', many=True)`

You didn't specified a `related_name` at M2M field so the default naming is applied which is `'Intermediate model name'_set` and if you want to use the fields on M2M relation you have to tell the serializer where to look for.

EDIT:
Camel removed from `articlefield_set`, model name is always converted to lower case

Comment: Thank you for answer! Got same error: BoardField object has no attribute ArticleField_set. Tried to change ArticleField_set to article_field_set (DB name) also - same result.

Comment: Sry, I forgot to mention that model name is always converted to lower case, try articlefield_set

Comment: I made a mistake in prev comment: current error is `Article object has no attribute ArticleField_set`. Not BoardField. Lower case `articlefield_set` gave same result :(

Comment: make sure you are using through correctly if the intermediate model is declared after your model you have to specify app_name first and through is like this through='your_app_name.ArticleField', also get rid of through_fields I think you don't need it, after doing this try again

Comment: So, it works now. Problem was in Admin point, where I set wrong `fk_name` during experiments and forgot about it. After it was removed, `articlefield_set` start working. Thank you :)